# xslt is not passing id to the url

Tags: html, xml, xslt

My xslt code is building the url but not passing in the id value. Can someone tell me why.

Here is the url my xslt code is building:

```
<img alt="No Caption Provided No Attribution Noted" src="http://ps2000-graphics-test.bna.com/view/png/{@id}.png" id="orca1627" onclick="$(this).image_popup('ptln','orca1627.png')" onload="$(this).image_resize()" class="inline_image">
```

Here is my xslt code:

```
 <xsl:template match="image[@cd.display='inline']">
      <img alt="{link.text}" src="{concat('http://ps2000-graphics-', $system.env, '.bna.com/view/png/{@id}.png')}" id="{@id}" onClick="$(this).image_popup('ptln','{@id}.png')" onLoad="$(this).image_resize()" class="inline_image"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't nest `{}`.

Try this:

```
src="{concat('http://ps2000-graphics-', $system.env, '.bna.com/view/png/', @id, '.png')}" ....
```

Comment: @ReazurRahman You can also do `<img src="http://ps2000-graphics-{$system.env}.bna.com/view/png/{@id}.png" />`. You can use multiple `{ }` in the value, just as long as they are not nested.

Comment: @TimC even better! :-)